# Universal Analytics - 3rd Party Payment Gateway

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

Our website is currently tracking with Universal Analytics via Tag Manager. Our check-out process includes getting redirected to a 3rd party payment gateway before going to the Thank You Page.

So, it would look like this:

site.com/checkout --> site.com/payment  --> security.com --> site.com/thankyou

Security.com is a 3rd party site and I am unable to add the tracking code there.

I'd like to be able to see who are able to get past the security.com stage and make it to the site.com/thankyou page. But with this setup, my reports show that after site.com/payment, the visitors exit. Then they return to the site with security.com as the referral page and site.com/thankyou as the landing page.

Any way I can set this up so I can see who actually makes it from checkout to the Thank You page?

Answer (score 5):

Goto Admin -> Property Settings -> Tracking info -> Referral Exclusion List and enter the domain name of you payment gateway (does not work for data that already has been recorded).